# Cannot concat multiple strings

Tags: c#

i'm trying to build a string and it is giving error, i'm sharing my code please guide me

```
public static bool Send(string Email, string ProcessID, string Name, string Part, string MFG, string TicketTotal)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string html = @"Dear, " + Name + "<br><br>" + "We are sending the price for your reference" + "<br><br>"

    + @"<table><thead style='background-color: #006DCC;color: white;padding:10px;width:700px;'>
        <tr>
            <th style='background-color:#006DCC;color: white;'>
                Part No
            </th>
            <th>
                Manufacturer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>" +

    @"<tbody style='background-color: #EEEEEE;'>" +
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        @"<tr>                                                
        <td style='background-color: #EEEEEE;'>" +
        @"<span>" + Part + "</span>" +
        "</td>" +

        @"<td>" + "<span>" + MFG + "</span>" + "</td>" +

        @"</tr>"
    } +

    @"</tbody></table>" +
    @"<br><br>" + "Total Amount: " + TicketTotal + "<br>" + "Process ID: " + ProcessID + "<br><br>"

    + @"For more inquiry please visit <a href='#' target='_blank'> Contact</a>"
    + @"<br><br>" + "Best Regards" + "<br><br>" + "Address: Address here" + "<br>"
    + @"Tel: Number" + "<br>" + "Fax: number" + "<br>" + "<a href='#' target='_blank'>abc</a>";                        
}
```

i want to add ten rows in table using loop, i have searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution. please guide me

Comment: might i suggest a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: or for that matter a templating engine?

Comment: Why don't you use htmlTable class instead of string manipulation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for the comment, actually i'm sending html email and need to concat different string values

Comment: @DanielA.White  thanks for the comment, actually i'm sending html email and need to concat different string values

Comment: @DanielA.White he is using a string builder.

Comment: @RandRandom i don't see it being used, at least not properly.

Comment: @Usama htmlTable class has an innerhtml property.

Comment: A refresher for you [How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) Without being rude, I think that when we see basic errors like these we should give an help posting some relevant information to correct the basics instead of spoon feeding the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that you were sending html based emails. I've done that too. The easiest way that I found was to put a HTML file as your resource with specific areas of the email with "tags" in them. For instance I chose %USERNAME% for obviously the username. I was then able to use the resource as a string, and do a `string.Replace` for the tags that I had. This served 2 purposes. One it was very easy to ready. And two it was easy to edit and preview my HTML. Here is what my code looked like in the end.

```
public override string GenerateEmailBody()
{
    var htmlBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("htmlEmail\\dliHTML.html");
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%AUTHOR%", Author);
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%REV%", Revision);
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%REPO%", Repo);
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%LOG%", Log);
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%DATE%", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%ADDED%",GetUList("Added",Added));
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%DELETED%",GetUList("Deleted",Deleted));
    htmlBody = htmlBody.Replace("%MODIFIED%",GetUList("Modified",Modified));
    return htmlBody;
}
```

You see that I did make a ULList. Which there probably is a better way of doing it, but that method isn't too horrible..

```
private string GetUList(string header, string[] list)
{
    if (list==null) return string.Empty;
    if (list.Length==0) return string.Empty;

    var ulist = GetHeaderString(3, header);
    ulist += "<UL>";
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        ulist += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", element);
    }
    ulist += "</UL>";

    return ulist;
}
```

**EDIT**

here is the "Get header String" method that i forgot to add

```
private string GetHeaderString(int size, string message)
{
    return string.Format("<H{0}>{1}</H{0}>" ,size, message);
}
```

Comment: @Usama - Doesnt this look like nice and neat? This is a far better option.

Comment: While something is missing this is definitively a better approach

Comment: @Steve I can add what is missing. What did I forget to add?

Comment: Not important, just the code for GetHeaderString

Comment: @Steve Just for you :) added it...

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, this is the total **wrong** way to go about doing this.

But to give you a nudge in the right direction by explaining **why** this isn't working see below.

You're trying to concatenate a loop to a string. You cant do this:

```
@"<tbody style='background-color: #EEEEEE;'>" + // this plus sign is the problem
          for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
         {
            @"<tr>      //etc.
```

You need to add to the string inside the loop:

```
string html = @"Dear, " + Name + "<br><br>" + "We are sending the price for your reference" + "<br><br>"

            + @"<table><thead style='background-color: #006DCC;color: white;padding:10px;width:700px;'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style='background-color:#006DCC;color: white;'>
                                                    Part No
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Manufacturer
                                                </th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>" +

              @"<tbody style='background-color: #EEEEEE;'>"; \\terminate the line. 

//start the loop
 for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
         {
           html += @"<tr>                                                
                    <td style='background-color: #EEEEEE;'>" +
                    @"<span>" + Part + "</span>" +
                "</td>" +

                 @"<td>" + "<span>" + MFG + "</span>" + "</td>" +

            @"</tr>"; // not plus
        }

html +=  @"</tbody></table>" +
     @"<br><br>" + "Total Amount: " + TicketTotal + "<br>" + "Process ID: " + ProcessID + "<br><br>"

     + @"For more inquiry please visit <a href='#' target='_blank'> Contact</a>"
     + @"<br><br>" + "Best Regards" + "<br><br>" + "Address: Address here" + "<br>"
     + @"Tel: Number" + "<br>" + "Fax: number" + "<br>" + "<a href='#' target='_blank'>abc</a>";
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, how can i do that?

Comment: @Usama look at this code/edit. That shows you how to do it.